# (beginner) How to dispatch in reactNative?

Tags: redux

I'm new to react and reactNative.

What is "dispatch is not a function. dispatch is an instance of Object."?

mapStateToProps works well.
However, mapDispatchToProps don't work.

I need to handle the nested action.

My Question is that
1. How Can I solve this problem(I want to just dispatch.)?

My code is below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class User extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
        <Text onPress={this.props.onKabaya}>kabaya?</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: state.User.user.name
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch = ({
  onKabaya: state => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_XXX' })
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(User);

//reducer
const INITIAL_STATE = { //nested action?
  user: {
    name: 'JOE'
  },
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_XXX':
      return {
        user: {
          name: 'XXX'
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Is there js ninja?
thanks.

Comment: mapDispatchToProps should be a function, you are missing an arrow there

Comment: oh, I'm so stupid.
thanks Zarczynksi.
I' delete my question.